# Why mapper value has to be Writable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a question regarding Mapper key/value being writable. Since(Assuming) the input format is running on the same machine as the Mapper is running why does the input key have to be writable.

Is it because input format is running on a different JVM? if not the value object can be sent to mapper directly right?

New to hadoop so pardon me if this is too basic

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Writable types allow Hadoop to read and write the data in a serialized form so it can be sent over the wire.

Whenever possible, Hadoop tries to assign the map tasks to nodes where the data in question is local to that node. This is called Data Locality.

However, this is not the case always.

In case, it does not get a slot open on the node with the data, the data needs to transferred across the network to another node where the map task has been assigned.

Edit:
The key and values to a mapper are objects and the value object implements Writable. So I don't think you can get away without implementing the Writable interface for your value.

Comment: Did you mean if the mapper node and the data node are not same the input formatter will run on the datanode and the records will be serialized in the data node and deserialized in the mapper node. Actually i dont have a reducer(though i need a data input formatter) and was wondering if i can get away without implementing the writable interface for my mapper value.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you earlier. The keys and values in a mapper are objects and the value object implements Writable. So I don't think you can get away without writing the writable interface. Hope this helps. I will update my answer too with this.